# CheckStyle checks not been ignored

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I have set up my checkstyle checks in my pom.xml as follows

```
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suppressionsLocation>
                        checkstyle-suppressions.xml
                    </suppressionsLocation>
                    <suppressionsFileExpression>
                        checkstyle-suppressions.xml
                    </suppressionsFileExpression>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

my checkstyle-supressions.xml file contains the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
     "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.0//EN"
     "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_0.dtd">

<suppressions>
  <suppress checks="JavadocStyleCheck"
             files="**/*.java"
             />
  <suppress checks="JavadocTypeCheck"
             files="**/*.java"
             />
  <suppress checks="JavadocVariableCheck"
             files="**/*.java"
             />
  <suppress checks="FileTabCharacterCheck"
             files="**/*.java"
             />
</suppressions>
```

I want that when i run mvn site, the check style plugin does not report any JavaDoc comments or errors relating to tab characters. But this does not work. How can i achieve this ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Your `files` attributes in the `suppress` nodes are missing a `"`

Comment: Is this related to Android? If not, can you remove the tag?

Answer (score 4):

The [CheckStyle:SuppressionFilter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html) told us as

> A suppressions XML document contains a set of `suppress` elements, where each `suppress` element can have the following attributes:
>
> 1. **files** - a ***regular expression*** matched against the file name associated with an audit event. It is mandatory.
> 2. **checks** - a ***regular expression*** matched against the name of the check associated with an audit event. Optional if id is specified.
> 3. **id** - a string matched against the id of the check associated with an audit event. Optional if checks is specified.
> 4. **lines** - a comma-separated list of values, where each value is ***an integer*** or a range of integers denoted by integer-integer. It is optional.
> 5. **columns** - a comma-separated list of values, where each value is ***an integer*** or a range of integers denoted by integer-integer. It is optional.

Since the `files` is a `regular expression`, you can test the configure online at [Regular Expression Test Page for Java](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

If the `files` is `**/*.java`, when apply the `regular expression` with `com.test.My.java` the result is failure as `Dangling meta character '*' near index 0 **/*.java ^`

Then **the solution is** setting the `files` as `.*\.java` , when apply the `regular expression` with `com.test.My.java` the result is **matches(): yes**, **lookingAt(): yes**, **find(): yes** and **group(0): com.test.My.java**.

The plugin configuration should be the following:-

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
      <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
      <suppressionsFileExpression>checkstyle.suppressions.file</suppressionsFileExpression>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The [checkstyle:checkstyle](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html) told us as

1. **suppressionsLocation**: Specifies the location of the suppressions XML file to use.
   **This parameter is resolved as resource, URL, then file**. If successfully resolved, the contents of the suppressions XML is copied into the `${project.build.directory}/checkstyle-supressions.xml` file before being passed to Checkstyle for loading.
2. **suppressionsFileExpression** The key to be used in the properties for the suppressions file. **Default value is: *checkstyle.suppressions.file***.

Please refer to [Maven Checkstyle Plugin: Using a Suppressions Filter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/suppressions-filter.html) for further information.

I hope this may help.

Comment: I've edited for providing the Maven Checkstyle Plugin configuration.