# Override one rule in maven checkstyle

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I am currently using maven checkstyle with the google rules.

Whenever I run it I get the message `[...] (coding) HiddenField: 'userId' hides a field.` which I want to hide without creating my own rule xml file.

Is there a way to override a rule in checkstyle without replacing the whole xml file?

My code so far:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can suppress rules using an additional suppressions file. You can see an example at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/suppressions-filter.html

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and it seems like the suppression file is not used. No matter what path I enter, it doesn't make a difference, even invalid ones.

Comment: @Freddy Did you see [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15828041/1743880)? Can you post the suppression file you tried?

Comment: I now have the solution. My configuration was in the wrong place. I needed to configure it for each goal.