# Why my checkstyle-supressions are ignored?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I have problem. It looks like my checkstyle-supressions are ignored. Im sure that path to file is correct (checkstyle.xml is loaded correctly), but checkstyle-supressions aint working. Do you know whot could be wrong?
 Below is my maven configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    ...
    <profiles>
        <profile>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    ...

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.10</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <configLocation>custom-checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                            <suppressionsLocation>custom-checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
                            <includeTestSourceDirectory>false</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                            <enableFilesSummary>true</enableFilesSummary>
                            <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                            <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>check</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
    ...
</project>
```

And my custom-checkstyle-supressions file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
        "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.0//EN"
        "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_0.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress checks=".*"
              files="src/main/java/model/Player.java"/>
</suppressions>
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CheckStyle checks not been ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573743/checkstyle-checks-not-been-ignored)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="custom-checkstyle-suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

to Checker module in checstyle.xml